# Create a physicsShape the same size as the geometry of a node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have two boxes. The top box has a dynamic physicsBody attached to it, the bottom box has a static body attached to it.

The physicShapes are created with:

```
topBox.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: nil)
bottomBox.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: nil)
```

When they come to rest, the box at the top is higher than it should be, suggesting that the physicsShape is larger than it should be. This is the objects at rest:

[image]

How do you create a physicsShape the same size/shape as as the geometry of the node you wish to attach it to?

FYI: The `SCNScene` comes from an imported DAE file, exported from Cheetah 3D.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: No. I couldn't get it to work properly from an imported DAE object.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue despite creating the shape from scratch. I think the issue is the default `SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType` value of `convexHull` will create a `convex polyhedron roughly enclosing the geometry`. This is always bigger than a box. You can confirm this by turning on `.showPhysicsShapes` debug option:

```
sceneView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes
```

So the below code help a bit by using `.boundingBox` option

```
let boxBodyShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0),
                                    options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.boundingBox])

let boxBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: boxBodyShape)
```

Comment: You are a god among men, sir.  Thank You.  Much Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.1 / Xcode 9.3**

Instead of assigning with a nil/NULL, use the geometry of the actual node.

```
let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.20, height: 0.25, length: 0.10, chamferRadius: 0)

let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: node.geometry)
let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: physicsShape)
node.physicsBody = physicsBody
```

that'll do it.

Answer (score 3):

you need to make your **static physicsBody** of type `concavePolyhedron`

here is an example:

```
let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: shape, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron, SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale: scale]))
```

optionally you can define a scale factor for the `physicsBody`